# How to add a small delay to an intersection observer in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, intersection-observer

I am using an intersection observer in vue 3 to trigger an component with a v-if when the component is in the viewport. This is because I have 700+ rows and for UX reasons we don't want to use pagination or lazyloading.

Now is the case: when you scroll from the top to the bottom really fast, every component gets visible because the v-if gets triggered.

Now is my question, can you add a short "debounce" of 100ms or so to the intersection observer's `isIntersecting` doesn't trigger on each component when you scroll really fast.

This is my code, it works like a charm but it triggers every component's v-if (isActive) on a very fast scroll which makes the page very slow.

My Init function.

```
const initObserver = () => {
  observer.disconnect();
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".observer-rating");
  sections.forEach((section) => {
    observer.observe(section);
  });
};
```

The onMounted hook

```
onMounted(() => {
  initObserver();
});
```

My Observer

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  (entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      meetings.value[entry.target.dataset.meeting].lessongroups[
        entry.target.dataset.lessongroup
      ].ratings[entry.target.dataset.rating].isActive = entry.isIntersecting;
    });
  },
  {
    rootMargin: "1000px",
  }
);
```

My HTML

```
            <div
              v-for="(rating, r) in lessonGroup.ratings"
              :key="r"
              class="observer-rating mb-2 border-b"
              :data-rating="r"
              :data-meeting="m"
              :data-lessongroup="l"
            >
              <StudentSingleRatingV2
                 v-if="rating.isActive"
                :rating="rating"
                :meeting="meeting"
                @update-rating="
                  validateRating(rating, meeting.settings, meeting.id)
                "
              />
              <div v-else class="bg-white" style="height: 100px" />
            </div>
```

The v-else here serves as a placholder

Comment: You could use this overall to support your [use-case of long lists](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller). You could also `pause` this IntersectionObserver](https://vueuse.org/core/useIntersectionObserver/#useintersectionobserver) just before scrolling. Or even simpler, jump to that place directly rather than scrolling. But a debounce will be more tricky to handle overall in that situation IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I indeed looked at the vue-virtual-scroller but this doesn't fit our case. The IntersectionObserver which can be paused seems interesting indeed. Will take a look at that thanks. Hoping for more responses too though!

Comment: That's just a very efficient way of dealing with big lists of things without hurting your performance.